# Email is not being updated

Tags: support, email

I have tried to update my Email account to the email I use as the default: justin17862@gmail.com. But each time I do that, there is no popup (success or failure). I also see the verified-email-set and the HTTP message is OK.

[image]

But when I reload the page, there is nothing changed, the same previous email is shown to me.

[image]

Any help for changing my Email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hrm. Not sure if this is intentional or not... we probably should propagate the changes you make on the preferences page back to your actual profile. However, in the meantime:

Try updating the email address from [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762944/afzaal-ahmad-zeeshan) instead. Click "edit" (instead of "preferences") and set a new email. You can also optionally copy your changes to every other site profile you have.

Note that this isn't the same as changing your login credentials, newsletter subscriptions, or email notification settings.

Comment: Well the changes are present there! But not on this page ...

Comment: Can you please make the email field there **not** look like it is editable? I wasted some time there just now, because there is no feedback and no hint at all.

Comment: @toscho But it *is* editable. It's just not editing what you are expecting it to. (Which, I admit, is a problem.)

Comment: @AnnaLear No, it doesn’t change the email address. I tried that with two different browsers. The submit button went grey, that was the only result. After a reload, the old email was still there. That field is _de facto_ not editable, you have to change it in `/edit`, not in `/preferences`.