# Can't update email for notifications

Tags: bug, profile-page, email-notification, preferences

When I try to update my notification email, it doesn't seem to work on any SE site. I fill in my new address at "Send emails to," then click on "Save email settings." After that, the "Save email settings" button is gray and nothing seems to happen. If I leave the preferences page and come back, the old email address is still there. Any idea what this problem might be?

This seems to be similar to, but not the same as, this problem: [Email is not being updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222545/email-is-not-being-updated) By clicking on "edit," I can change my email address, but then when I go to preferences, my notification email is still the same. Are these supposed to be two independently controllable email addresses?

Comment: The button becoming gray is the expected behavior, and means "changes were saved", the bug is that the email is not being saved.